# Perl date comparison doesn't work

Tags: perl, date, time, comparison

I am trying to do some date comparison in Perl but seems it is not working as expected. What might I be doing wrong?

```
my $lCurrentTime = Time::Piece->new;
my $l15MinsAGo   = $lCurrentTime - 900;
my $lEffDate     = Time::Piece->strptime($opt_effdate, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S');

print("\n lCurrentTime = $lCurrentTime     l15MinsAGo = $l15MinsAGo     lEffDate = $lEffDate\n");

if ($lEffDate < $lCurrentTime) {
    print("Eff date $lEffDate is smaller than 15 mins ago $l15MinsAGo\n");
} elsif ($lEffDate >= $lCurrentTime) {
    print("Eff date $lEffDate is larger than 15 mins ago $l15MinsAGo\n");
}
```

This prints:

```
lCurrentTime = Fri Jun  2 10:32:53 2017     
l15MinsAGo = Fri Jun  2 10:17:53 2017     
lEffDate = Fri Jun  2 10:07:00 2017

Eff date Fri Jun  2 10:07:00 2017 is larger than 15 mins ago Fri Jun  2 10:17:53 2017
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I would suggest you to compare unixtimestamps.

Comment: You use `$lCurrentTime` in both conditions, what you probably wanted is `$l15MinsAGo`

Comment: @Patrick85: There's no reason to do that. The `Time::Piece` module overloads `<=>` to compare the epoch value of both date-times, so just `<` is fine.

Comment: Crucial piece of information missing. What is in `$opt_effdat`?

Answer (score 2):

What timezone are you in?

This may enlighten you as to what is happening:

```
print $lEffDate -> epoch,"\n";
print $lCurrentTime -> epoch,"\n";

print $lEffDate -> tzoffset,"\n";
print $lCurrentTime -> tzoffset,"\n";
```

I suspect that (like me) the `strptime` date is zero offset, and the one you got from `new` is your timezone.

So there's a couple of hours different in the actual timestamps.

To correct this - there's a few different approaches:

- Parse a timezone into your string, using `%Z` or `%z`.
- Adjust the time by the timezone `$time += $time->localtime->tzoffset;`
- Just work in 'UTC' - `strptime` is assuming it. So you can instead do `$lCurrentTime = gmtime;` I think.

Comment: Yes the issue seems to be the timezone.
Your code prints:

    1496394360
    1496395335
    0
    7200

Hence 2 hours difference in the timezones. How do I fix this i.e. make the strptime use the same timezone?

Comment: I've updated with some possible answers. Depends how important preserving TZ information is to you. But the simple answer would be - use `gmtime`.

Comment: @Sobrique: The best way: call `$lCurrentTime->strptime` instead of `Time::Piece->strptime` to create a date-time with the same time zone and daylight savings. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems here:

- The test `lEffDate < $lCurrentTime` should be `lEffDate < $l15MinsAGo`
- You are creating `$lEffDate` without a time zone, whereas `$lCurrentTime` is created with the local time zone, Daylight savings are current in effect, so the to are bound to differ

Also

- `Time::Piece` exports `localtime` which overrides the built-in operator. It functions in the same way both as the original call and as a `Time::Piece` object according to how it is used
- Please don't use `hungarianNotationAndCamelCase`. It's not very readable, expecially for those whose first language isn't English. Experienced Perl developers mostly use `snake_case`, and your leading `l` presumably means "longword", which is irrelevant on Perl

You can parse a date in the same time zone as the local one by calling `strptime` on `$lCurrentTime` instead of on the class name `Time::Piece`

Like this

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds 'ONE_MINUTE';

my $opt_eff_date = '02-06-2017 10:00:00';

my $now         = localtime;
my $past_15mins = $now - 15 * ONE_MINUTE;
my $eff_date    = $now->strptime( $opt_eff_date, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S' );

print <<END;

now         = $now
past_15mins = $past_15mins
eff_date    = $eff_date

END

if ( $eff_date < $past_15mins ) {
    print "Effective date $eff_date is smaller than 15 mins ago $past_15mins\n";
}
else {
    print "Effective date $eff_date is larger than 15 mins ago $past_15mins\n";
}
```

#### output

```
now         = Fri Jun  2 10:36:26 2017
past_15mins = Fri Jun  2 10:21:26 2017
eff_date    = Fri Jun  2 10:00:00 2017

Eff date Fri Jun  2 10:00:00 2017 is smaller than 15 mins ago Fri Jun  2 10:21:26 2017
```

Comment: "You can parse a date in the same time zone as the local one by calling strptime on $lCurrentTime instead of on the class name Time::Piece"

This is what I needed and didn't know. Thx a lot.

Comment: @vlatkovr: It's actually a bit messy because it produces an object that may have a different time zone and different daylight savings settings from the base object, but which together amount to the same offset.